# Specman - How can I control passive/active agents

Tags: verification, uvm, specman

I build uart verification environment.
I have uart_tx_agent and uart_rx_agent.
The uart_tx_agent has dummy bfm which control cts port and doesn't have driver.
The uart_rx_agent has bfm and driver which has uart_sequence.

uart_env.e : 
In the uart_env I initiate the agents as the following

```
unit uart_env_u like uvm_env {
   uart_tx_agent: uart_tx_agent_u is instance;
   uart_rx_agent: uart_rx_agent_u is instance;
};

unit uart_tx_agent_u like uvm_agent {
   keep soft active_passive == PASSIVE;
};

unit uart_rx_agent_u like uvm_agent {
   keep soft active_passive == PASSIVE;   
};
```

uart_tx_agent.e:

```
extend uart_rx_agent_u{
   uart_rx_monitor : RX uart_monitor_u is instance;
   when ACTIVE uart_rx_agent_u
   {
      uart_bfm : uart_rx_bfm_u is instance;
      driver: uart_driver_u is instance;
   };   
};

unit uart_rx_bfm_u like uvm_bfm{
};

sequence uart_sequence using 
   item = uart_frame_s,
   created_driver = uart_driver_u;
```

uart_tx_agent.e:

```
extend uart_tx_agent_u{
   uart_tx_monitor : TX uart_monitor_u is instance;
   uart_tx_scb: uart_tx_scoreboard_u is instance;
   when ACTIVE uart_tx_agent_u {
      uart_bfm : uart_tx_bfm_u is instance;
   };
};

unit uart_tx_bfm_u like uvm_bfm{
};
```

In the tx_test I have only one Main sequence - vr_ad_sequence, and I do the following:

```
extend MAIN vr_ad_sequence {
   .....
   .....  
   keep uart_env.uart_tx_agent.active_passive == ACTIVE;
   ...
};
```

In the rx_test I have two MAIN sequences:

```
extend MAIN uart_sequence {
   ....
   ....
   body() @driver.clock is only {
   };
};

extend MAIN vr_ad_sequence {
   .....
   .....  
   keep uart_env.uart_tx_agent.active_passive == ACTIVE;
   ...
};
```

But it does work as I expected.
In both of the tests the agents are staying PASSIVE (with no bfm /driver).

Answer (score 0):

the sequences are being generated only after the test starts, so it's too late to set the agent as ACTIVE at that point.

put this constraint in some higher level in the hierarchy. for example - in the env containing this agent

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between the unit hierarchy, which is generated at the beginning of the simulation, and structs. The latter can be dynamically generated at any time. 
Hence any constraints in e.g. sequences generated at a later point in simulation cannot change the unit hierarchy. It's also bad style to do this.